# How to debug the error thrown by Doctrine

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

#### What ?

This is the error thrown by my doctrine when writing my query

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 971 near '(\n          ': Error: Class '(' is not defined.
```

How can i detect the exact position where the error occurs in my doctrine style of writing, in short how to read this error ?

#### my Query pattern

```
 $qb1 = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

 $qb1->select('
   count(case when (boolShit) then id end)
')
->from(someTable);
$qb1->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Can you please post your doctrine code

Comment: @KishanPatel Doctrine code doesn't matter as this type of error comes in for any syntax error in the sql queries.
For reference I've updated the patter of my doctrine query. 
What i want is to how to pinpoint this location that is thrown in doctrine error where it occurs ?

Comment: @RahulGupta This is not SQL error, but DQL.

Comment: @JakubMatczak Do yo know how to debug this?

Comment: I can see similar questions on SO and it looks like a problem with Doctrine. I think I would try with `SUM(CASE WHEN boolShit THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: You dont need to debug, you need to read how Doctrine ORM works or you choose to use doctrine's DBAL which generates normal mysql arrays which you can fetch to array's and not to objects what ORM does. Read this article: http://blog.ajnicholls.com/orm-vs-dbal-explained/

Comment: @JakubMatczak Can't use SUM in my case both has completely diff meanings because case will return an id else NULL (which is ignored by count) that could be duplicate so my aim is to do COUNT( DISTINCT (CASE SHIT) )

Comment: @Frankbeen The article is great ! We've setup ORM in our project but for complex queries DBAL is really easy & efficient.
My question actually is how can i point the location of errors (mentioned above) that are coming when generating DBAL like queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Symfony2, you can debug it with using `app_dev.php`. If you do so, you are able to press plus button beneath the error output that you've shown. This pus button is on the end of the line starting with `[QueryException]`.

If you'll find this magic "plus button" you will find the exact line of getting result (i.e. getResult(), getArrayResult()...)

Example output with "plus button":

[image: Example]

Comment: We don't render an html like this, this is actually a rest api & the response is returned as a json or text. :( Thanks btw

Comment: But still you can change Response type just to debug. To do this you shoud put in response `<html>` tags.

Comment: @RahulGupta - did you try to use xdebug ? Except for its slowness it will let you do such debugging.